# Creating Controllers / Views for a Rails 4 Engine in App

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing, rails-engines

Using Rails 4 I have an engine called **Core** that contains business rules and data objects for a system we're using. This is designed to be lean and in included in a few different apps.

I am creating an app that will contain some special CRUD screens for some of this core data, and I am not sure the best way to set up routing.

In other words, **I want to create views and controllers for an engine's models *without* mounting the engine in my routes.**

However, after running `rails g scaffold_controller core::rep`, I can't seem to get the url helper methods loaded. In my config/routes.rb:

```
namespace :core do
    resources :reps
end
```

rake routes returns:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
    core_reps GET    /core/reps(.:format)          core/reps#index  
              POST   /core/reps(.:format)          core/reps#create 
 new_core_rep GET    /core/reps/new(.:format)      core/reps#new    
edit_core_rep GET    /core/reps/:id/edit(.:format) core/reps#edit   
     core_rep GET    /core/reps/:id(.:format)      core/reps#show   
              PATCH  /core/reps/:id(.:format)      core/reps#update 
              PUT    /core/reps/:id(.:format)      core/reps#update 
              DELETE /core/reps/:id(.:format)      core/reps#destroy
```

Which seems fine.
However, upon navigating to URL: **/core/reps**

```
Showing /app/views/core/reps/index.html.erb where line #14 raised:
undefined method `edit_core_rep_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000002adf578>:0x00000002adc3a0>
```

Which I take to mean that the url_helpers aren't being correctly set up, and I have a growing suspicion that I am approaching this problem in the wrong way.

Is there something I am missing? Should I be trying to extend Engine Controllers in the app?

**Can I use an Application's helpers with an Engine's models? Or do I have to mount the engine?**

I know I can `rails g scaffold_controller rep` and then just patch the controller to load the data from the engine, but that doesn't seem quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the proxy helpers bit in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.8/engines.html#routes ?